# Does there exist a "stochastically universal" two-column matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $\mathcal{R}_{m\times n}$ denote the family of all $m\times n$ matrices with elements in $[0,1]$, and let $\mathcal{S}_{m\times n}$ denote the family of all $m\times n$ row-stochastic matrices, that is, matrices $\mathbf{A}\in\mathcal{R}_{m\times n}$ with sum of elements in each row equal to $1$.
Let us say that a matrix $\mathbf{A}\in\mathcal{R}_{n\times 2}$ is *stochastically universal* if for every $m\ge 1$ and every matrix $\mathbf{B}\in\mathcal{R}_{m\times 2}$ there exists a row-stochastic matrix $\mathbf{C}\in\mathcal{S}_{m\times n}$ such that $\mathbf{B}=\mathbf{C}\mathbf{A}$.

**Question:** Does there exist a stochastically universal matrix $\mathbf{A}\in\mathcal{R}_{n\times 2}$, for some $n\ge 1$? If so, how to characterize all stochastically universal matrices?

**Note:** This question is motivated by an attempt to answer a [question on probability kernels](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3074484/392689). When considering finite measurable spaces, probability kernels correspond to stochastic matrices and the composition of kernels corresponds to the matrix multiplication. A matrix $\mathbf{A}\in\mathcal{R}_{n\times 2}$ encodes two stochastic matrices in $\mathcal{S}_{n\times 2}$, that is, two probability kernels from an $n$-element measurable space into two $2$-element measurable spaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $\mathbf{A}=\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&1\\1&1\\0&0\end{pmatrix}$.
Then for every $\mathbf{B}=\begin{pmatrix}a_1&b_1\\a_2&b_2\\\vdots&\vdots\\a_m&b_m\end{pmatrix}\in\mathcal{R}_{m\times 2}$ we can take
$$\mathbf{C}=\begin{pmatrix}a_1-u_1&b_1-u_1&u_1&1-a_1-b_1+u_1\\a_2-u_2&b_2-u_2&u_2&1-a_2-b_2+u_2\\\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots\\a_m-u_m&b_m-u_m&u_m&1-a_m-b_m+u_m\end{pmatrix},$$ where $u_i=\min\{a_i,b_i\}$, for every $i\in\{1,2,\dots,m\}$. It is straightforward to check that $\mathbf{C}$ is a row-stochastic matrix and $\mathbf{B}=\mathbf{C}\mathbf{A}$, hence $\mathbf{A}$ is stochastically universal.

It is also clear that if $\mathbf{A}\in\mathcal{R}_{n\times 2}$ contains rows $(1,0)$, $(0,1)$, $(1,1)$, $(0,0)$ then $\mathbf{A}$ is stochastically universal.

Let us show that this condition is also necessary.
Let $\mathbf{A}\in\mathcal{R}_{n\times 2}$ be stochastically universal, and let $\mathbf{B}=\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&1\\1&1\\0&0\end{pmatrix}$. By the universality of $\mathbf{A}$ there exists $\mathbf{C}\in\mathcal{S}_{4\times n}$ such that $\mathbf{B}=\mathbf{C}\mathbf{A}$.
We prove that for every $i\in\{1,\dots,4\}$ there exists $j\in\{1,\dots,n\}$ such that $b_{i,1}=a_{j,1}$ and $b_{i,2}=a_{j,2}$. Let $i\in\{1,\dots,4\}$ and $k\in\{1,2\}$ be fixed. For $j\in\{1,\dots,n\}$ denote $a'_{j,k}=\left|b_{i,k}-a_{j,k}\right|$. Then either $a'_{j,k}=a_{j,k}-b_{i,k}$ for all $j$, or $a'_{j,k}=b_{i,k}-a_{j,k}$ for all $j$, hence $$\sum_{j=1}^nc_{i,j}\,a'_{j,k}=\left|b_{i,k}-\sum_{j=1}^nc_{i,j}\,a_{j,k}\right|=0.$$
Since $\sum_{j=1}^n c_{i,j}=1$ and $c_{i,j}\ge 0$ for every $j$, there exists $j$ such that $c_{i,j}>0$. Then $a'_{j,1}=a'_{j,2}=0$, hence $a_{j,1}=b_{i,1}$ and $a_{j,2}=b_{i,2}$.

Thus, a matrix $\mathbf{A}\in\mathcal{R}_{n\times 2}$ is stochastically universal if and only if it contains rows $(1,0)$, $(0,1)$, $(1,1)$ and $(0,0)$.